# How to convert VCD to DVD?

Tags: 10.04, software-recommendation

I have lots of VCDs which I want to convert to DVDs. Can you suggest me a software with GUI which would do it for me?

Thanks.

Comment: You understand that the quality of the videos will still be the same, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest **qdvdauthor** or **dvdrip** as gui based. But i HIGHLY suggest using console tools like **ffmpeg**, **mencoder** and similars. They do a fast, excellent job.

You can also MAKE an iso of a vcd with **acetoneiso**, **brasero** (Which comes by default in Ubuntu) or **k3b** (Which comes by default in Kubuntu) and then burn it like dvd with something like **devede**.

Remember that you can not make a video with higher quality than what it has in the beginning. In your case you cant make a vcd quality movie have a dvd quality. It is like a dvd quaility trying to have a blue-ray quality.

All the tools i suggested can be found in the **ubuntu software center** or **synaptic**.

If you are going to use all the tools for that then you should first make the vcd to iso and then test it by viewing it with vlc. If all is good then burn it with devede which will make it into dvd format (With an optional menu) and you can just burn it and watch it in your media player.

Us the following in console to have them all installed:

`sudo apt-get install vlc devede acetoneiso ubuntu-restricted-extras mencoder ffmpeg`

This should have you ready to transform anything to dvd.

Remember:

1. Make the ISO from the source. In your case a VCD. You can use acetoneiso or brasero for it.
2. OPEN the iso with VLC to watch it and see how it all came out. If good then open with DEVEDE

Comment: thanks , very helpful , I did not know vlc plays iso too , now I know  thanks again